# 404 Errors after update to Wordpress 3.7

Tags: wordpress

I just updated to WordPress 3.7 this morning, and I started getting 404 errors on one of my custom post types. I am implementing multiple CPT's through one plugin. All other CPT's are wotking fine except one.

The code for the same is below:

// Register Author Post Type

```
function custom_post_author() {
 $labels = array(
'name' => 'Authors',
'singular_name' => 'Author',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Author',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Author',
    'new_item' => 'New Author',
    'all_items' => 'All Authors',
    'view_item' => 'View Author',
    'search_items' => 'Search Authors',
    'not_found' =>  'No authors found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No authors found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Authors'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'authors' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/authors.png', dirname( __FILE__ )),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'comments')
  );

  register_post_type( 'author', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_author' );
```

The CPT is visible in the backend, but when I view any post on the frontend it gives a 404.
Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that WordPress 3.7 is not liking the custom post type to be defined as `author`. Changing it to `authors` is working fine. However that will also need an update in the wp_posts table.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar error: I could not go to any singular page of my custom post types. Updating the permalink settings did not help me either. I debugged a little bit and found out that somehow the rewrites for my custom post types had not been set in the $wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules() array.

All my custom post types are registered within a plugin. Then I remembered that I once read in the documentation that you would have to flush the rules on plugin activation/deactivation (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

So, I fixed my issue by adding flush_rewrite_rules() to the function that registers all my custom post types and I think it will help you too!

```
function register_my_custom_post_types()
{
  register_post_type( ... );

  // flush the rewrite_rules after registering the post types
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### I solved this problem using these steps :

Go to paramlink page from `WordPress`'s menu `Settings->paramlinks` and update the settings (don't need to change any settings) by clicking save changes (or maybe you don't need to update the settings, only visiting the `paramlinks` page is enough) and then try to view your custom posts. It'll show up.

Comment: My problem has been solved by these steps and it happened just a few minutes (30) ago.

Comment: Yes I know ... updating permalinks solves 404 errors. It seems WordPress 3.7 is not liking the custom post to be names as `author`.

Comment: I had same problem (updated to 3.7) and solved but don't know what else is wrong.