# 3.7 wordpress update causing all pages/post to be blank and uneditable

Tags: wordpress

While try to update my WordPress version into 3.7 the edit pages for my all post and pages look likes blank. got confused what would to do. But my website itself seems to be working fine and all the pages are visible.

I had enabled wp_debug into true but it doesn't show any kind of warnings or errors

Comment: Check this answer, if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583960/404-errors-after-update-to-wordpress-3-7/19584881#19584881

Comment: i cant find any solution

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme, does it still happens? There's no master list for 3.7 yet, but mostly everything applies: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-36-master-list

Answer (score 0):

in your root directory look for file `wp-config.php` in that file find

`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

And change it to

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Now your site will show errors instead of just blank screen !

Comment: already i had mention on my question. i tried it but it doesn't seems any error or warnings

Comment: right now the warning arises below like   Notice: is_feed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.) in /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3060